# I can't iterate through my list, it just says "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to check through a list to see if any of the strings inside it contain the word "Temperature" and I'm trying to use a for loop to do this but it doesn't seem to want to work.
It seems like it won't iterate because the list is all strings but I've used a for loop to iterate through strings before so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTFFR.png)

[The Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVi2O.png)

Comment: post your code and traceback as text, not as screenshot

Comment: Paste code as text, not as image

Comment: do `print(i)` You'll understand what happen. That is first-level debugging, when variables don't what you wang/raise errors : PRINT THEM to ensure they are what you think. `i` is a line, not an indice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve the value by `str` as the error says.
Try this:

```
print(i)
```

As you'll see, you'll get `str`.

A solution for this problem is as follows

1. Remove `line = split_lines[i]`
2. Change `line.contains("Temperature")` to `"Temperature" in i`
3. `temperature_string = i`

Comment: using `print(type(i))` and `print(repr(i))` would be more helpful in general since `print(1)` and `print("1")` are indistinguishable.